# Utilizing public variables

Tags: java, variables

I have created a game similar to snake in which the user is first prompted with a jpanel asking which difficulty they want, and whatever JButton they pick influences the size of the map as well as the delay between the snake movements. I have the map size working just fine, but the delay variable never seems to change. I suspect it has something to do with the way the timer is being casted, but I have no idea how to fix it. I am also wondering how when the program is first ran it seems some of the variables don't update, but the second time it is ran all of them are updated. Here is my class with the original variables and collision detection:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class GameEngine extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
   //creates the size of the panel as well as creating the resolution for all objects, including the players and food.
   static final int sWidth = 600;
   static final int sHeight = 600;
   public static int size = 24;
   static int objectSize = (sHeight*sWidth) / size;
   public static int delay = 100;
   final int playerX[] = new int[objectSize];
   final int playerY[] = new int[objectSize];
   int bodySize = 4;
   int score = 0;
   int appleX;
   int appleY;
   char direction = 'D';
   boolean started = false;
   Random random;
   Timer timer;
   boolean easy;
   JLabel score1;
   public static String difficulty;
   
   
    GameEngine(){
         
         random = new Random();
         this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sWidth,sHeight));
         this.setBackground(Color.black);
         this.setFocusable(true);
         this.addKeyListener(new UserMovement());
         gameStart();

            
         
   
   }
   public void gameStart() {
      
      newApple();
      started = true;
      timer = new Timer(delay,this);
      timer.start();

   
   
   }
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      draw(g);
      
   }
   
   public void drawHead(Graphics g) {
         g.setColor(new Color(100,252,0));
         g.fillRect(playerX[0], playerY[0], size, size);
   }
      public void draw(Graphics g) {
      if(started) {
      
   //draws the apples
   g.setColor(Color.red);
   g.fillOval(appleX, appleY, size, size);
   

   
   
   for (int i = 0; i < bodySize; i++) {
      if(i == 0) {
         drawHead(g);
         }
      else {
         g.setColor(new Color(60,180,0));
         g.fillRect(playerX[i], playerY[i], size, size);
   }
   }
   
   g.setColor(Color.white);
   g.setFont(new Font("Bold", Font.BOLD, 20));
   FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
   g.drawString("Score: " + score,(sWidth - metrics.stringWidth("Score: " + score))/2,g.getFont().getSize());
   }
   }
   public void newApple(){
      appleX = random.nextInt((int)(sWidth/size))*size;
      appleY = random.nextInt((int)(sHeight/size))*size;
   }
   
   //moves the player by using and modifying their coordinates   
   public void move() {
      for (int i = bodySize; i > 0; i--) {
         playerX[i] = playerX[i-1];
         playerY[i] = playerY[i-1];
   
   }
   
   switch(direction) {
   case 'W':
      playerY[0] = playerY[0] - size;
      break;
   case 'S':
      playerY[0] = playerY[0] + size;
      break;
   case 'A':
      playerX[0] = playerX[0] - size;
      break;
   case 'D':
      playerX[0] = playerX[0] + size;
      break;
      
      
    }  
    }
      
   public void checkFood() {
      if(playerX[0] == appleX && playerY[0] == appleY)
      {  
         bodySize++;
         score++;
         newApple();
   
      }
   }
   public void checkCol() {
      //checks for head collision with the body
      for(int i = bodySize; i > 0; i--) {
         if((playerX[0] == playerX[i]) && (playerY[0] == playerY[i])) {
            started = false;
         }
      }
      //checks if head touches any of the walls of the program
      if(playerX[0] < 0) {
         started = false;
      }
      
      if(playerX[0] > sWidth) {
         started = false;
      }
      
      if(playerY[0] < 0) {
         started = false;
      }
      
      if(playerY[0] > sHeight) {
         started = false;
      }
      
      if(started != true) {
         timer.stop();
         }
   
   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   
      if(started == true) {
         move();
         checkFood();
         checkCol();
      }
      repaint();
         
   }
   public class UserMovement extends KeyAdapter {
      @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
               if(direction != 'D') {
                  direction = 'A';
               }
               break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
               if(direction != 'A') {
                  direction = 'D';
               }
               break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
               if(direction != 'S') {
                  direction = 'W';
               }
               break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
               if(direction != 'W') {
                  direction = 'S';
               }
               break;
      }
   }
      
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
      }
      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      }
   }
}
```

and here is the code calling and changing the `delay` and `size` variables:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StartMenu extends JPanel {

   StartMenu()
   {
         JButton easy = new JButton();
         JButton hard = new JButton();
         this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,240));
         this.setLayout(null);
         this.setBackground(Color.black);
         this.setFocusable(true);
         easy.setBounds(75,40,200,40);
         hard.setBounds(75,120,200,40);
         this.add(easy);
         this.add(hard);
         
         easy.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            setVisible(false);
            new SnakeStart();
            GameEngine.size = 48;
            GameEngine.delay = 140;
            }
         });
         
         hard.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            setVisible(false);
            new SnakeStart();
            GameEngine.size = 24;
            GameEngine.delay = 70;
            }
         });
         
         
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `GameEngine` instance is created before the `StartMenu` action listeners are executed. If that assumption is correct, that means that `GameEngine.timer` with the default value of `delay` is created in the `GameEngine` constructor and is not updated after the `delay` is changed.

You need to make sure that you explicitly update your `timer` with the new `delay` value after `StartMenu` actions are called.